# How to convert integer values starting from 1 into one hot values?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with one column containing values from 1 to 7. How can I convert those values into one hot encoded values?

As far as I know, starting from 0 up to any values without any break one can use OneHotEncoder of SKlearn but since the numbers start from 1, I couldn't do it. This column is my dependent feature column for a classification problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use pandas `get_dummies` function ([docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html))

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'numerical_thing':[1,2,3,2,1,1,3,4,5,2,3,2,1]})
>>> pd.get_dummies(df.loc[:,'numerical_thing'])
    1  2  3  4  5
0   1  0  0  0  0
1   0  1  0  0  0
2   0  0  1  0  0
3   0  1  0  0  0
4   1  0  0  0  0
5   1  0  0  0  0
6   0  0  1  0  0
7   0  0  0  1  0
8   0  0  0  0  1
9   0  1  0  0  0
10  0  0  1  0  0
11  0  1  0  0  0
12  1  0  0  0  0
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I know this as well, but as I mentioned this column is the dependent column so can I have more than one column as dependent columns?